# Making an IE8 Accelerator for my website

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, accelerator

i have a file Accelerator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<os:openServiceDescription   
    xmlns:os="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/openservicedescription/1.0"> 
<os:homepageUrl>http://www.sapo.pt</os:homepageUrl>  
<os:display> 
  <os:name>Find on Sapo</os:name>
  <os:description>Find more information on Sapo</os:description> 
  <os:icon>http://msdn.microsoft.com/favicon.ico</os:icon>  
</os:display> 
<os:activity category="Search">  
  <os:activityAction context="selection">      
      <os:execute action="http://pesquisa.sapo.pt/" method="get"> 
        <os:parameter name="q" value="{selection}" type="text" /> 
      </os:execute>  
  </os:activityAction> 
</os:activity>
</os:openServiceDescription>
```

This not work get  me a error "threre are a problem wiyh accelerator's information" when go click in button in my html to install. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few rules.

1. You must serve the xml file from either an http or https protocol. Clicking on the link locally with the file: protocol will not work
2. The url's used should all be from the same domain, so try changing the favicon url to the sapo.pt domain